# Switching between groups of config values

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I have a small number of  entries in my App.Config file that will change depending on what type of testing I am doing. Is there a way to tell the app which group of settings to make use of? Below I have mocked up an `App.Config` example I was thinkning of.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <TestingScenario name="Scenario1">
      <add key="ApiKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      <add key="UserName" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      <add key="TokenId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </TestingScenario>
    <TestingScenario name="Scenario2">
      <add key="ApiKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      <add key="UserName" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      <add key="TokenId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </TestingScenario>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to have the application use **Scenario1** in one case and **Scenario2** in another? Deliniating which scenario to use in code would be fine as it would still save me from having to comment out and pasting in config values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the appSettings like that; instead, you'd want to create your own custom configuration section.  Here are some articles to see what it's capable of:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/customconfiguration/Custom_Configuration_Sections.aspx
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/customconfiguration/Configuration_Section_Validators.aspx
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/customconfiguration/Custom_Configuration_Collections.aspx

The idea is you create a class that inherits from ConfigurationSection, and then define properties on the section which you can set, similar to:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("DisplayInformation", DefaultValue=true)]
public bool DisplayInformation
{
    get
    {
       return (bool)this["DisplayInformation"];
    }
    set
    {
        this["DisplayInformation"] = value;
    }
}
```

The one article includes how to do collections, which in your example appSettings is the ConfigurationSection, TestingScenario is the list of items in a collection on the appSettings class, and the key and value are the properties on the entity in the list.